# Can I get JSON.stringify to include keys with value undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I use object looking like this (to keep track of some things):

```js
myObj = {
        key1: undefined,
        key2: undefined,
    }
     
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
console.log(Object.entries(myObj))
```

To my suprise I just noticed that `JSON.stringify(myObj)` just gives `{}`.

Looking at MDN the description of the `replacer` argument says (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object
>   are included in the resulting JSON string.

Which seems to be wrong.

Do I have to write a function for the `replacer` argument, or? (And is this a bug in Chrome? Or is the info at MDN wrong?)

Comment: What `replacer` argument? The object is null because it has no defined properties. Not sure what this has to do with replacer?

Comment: @Liam The second argument to [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Use null instead of undefined

Comment: @mplungjan I think `undefined` is preferred (since it easier for the js engine).

Comment: @Liam It has defined properties, but JSON.stringify misses them.

Comment: Would the person who wants to close the question please step forward and explain why?

Comment: [I already have...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062685/can-i-get-json-stringify-to-include-keys-with-value-undefined?noredirect=1#comment102521735_58062685). Can you explain what this has to do with replacer?

Comment: @Liam I have not tested, but I guessed I could make the `replace` function loop through the entries. Since that is a JavaScript function it should see the entries with value `undefined` (if I understand your answer).

Comment: Not in a (valid) JSON: `A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.`

Comment: Here is your replacer: `var string = JSON.stringify(
  obj,
  function(k, v) { return v === undefined ? null : v; }
);`

Comment: Thanks for the links to the older questions. Wonder why I missed them.

Comment: Hm, I think I know why I missed them. The info on MDN is not quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Undefined" is not a valid json value, even though it is valid in javascript. From the [official json standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (ECMA-404, Section 5)
For JSON, use null instead of undefined

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj = {
    key1: null,
    key2: null,
}));
```

Comment: I already answered this in a comment

Comment: Thanks, I see. That explains the behavior of `JSON.stringify`. But it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. (I thought it was about the argument to `JSON.stringify`.)

Comment: Any thoughts about such use of `null` and the JavaScript engine?